# Repetition Problem With Telegram Bot In Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I am trying to make a telegram bot with node js. What my bot do is making phone calls based on what the telegram user input. My bot works fine at the first execution but when I try to do multiple task it get stuck in a weird loop an bassicaly send the message one more time each time I give input.

Its like the code never break the switch and always listen for a number input.

Here is my code in node:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");

const port = 5000;
const app = express();

const Voice = require("@signalwire/realtime-api").Voice;

const { TOKEN, SERVER_URL } = process.env;
const URI = `/webhook/${TOKEN}`;

const TelegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const { reset, restart } = require("nodemon");
const nodemon = require("nodemon");
var chatId;

// replace the value below with the Telegram token you receive from @BotFather
const token = "<token>";

// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

bot.on("message", (msg) => {
  chatId = msg.chat.id;

  if (msg.text == "/call") {
    chooseBank();
  }




  if (msg.text == "/restart") {
    recover();
  }

});

//GIVE OPTION FOR THE CLIENT
function chooseBank() {
  bot.sendMessage(
    chatId,
    "CHOOSE THE BANK: \n\n1 RBC\n2 CIBC\n3 SCOTIA\n4 BMO\n5 NATIONAL\n6 TD\n7 PC-FINANCIAL\n8 DESJARDINS"
  );

  bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    switch (msg.text) {
      case "1":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "2":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "3":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "4":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "5":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "6":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "7":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
        break;
      case "8":
        bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          "ENTER THE CLIENTS NUMBER:\n\nEX: (+15142220000)"
        );
        
    }
  });
}

function recover(){
    chooseBank()
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
your text`
```

Here Are the example of running my bot in telegram:

[first execution works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBszw.png)

[repeat itself and add one more every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxodO.png)

Answer (score 0):

`on` method adds your code as listener as mentioned in [doc](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+on).

You need to register it only once. Move it outside of `chooseBank()`.

Comment: Ok but then how to I constantly listen to a message? How to have multiple level of user input? Say I have option A and B. If user choose option A, they get another series of options?

Comment: Your app is initialized once and "listens" message calls from telegram. You should set up your bot to differentiate different levels of messages. `msg` object should have all required info including user who sent the message, so you can track current state per user.